# Having images with caption automatically resize for different screens in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, screen-resolution, image-scaling

I'm editing a page in Wordpress, and I want the images to look the same on different screen resolutions and formats (desktop, mobile).

My image block looks like this:

```
<!-- wp:image {"id":xxxxx,"sizeSlug":"large"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large">
[caption id="attachment_yyyyy" align="aligncenter" width="748"]<img class="wp-image-yyyyy " src="<URL>" alt="" width="auto" height="auto" /> Caption under the image.[/caption]
<figcaption><span style="font-family: <font stuff>"> </span></figcaption>
</figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->
```

I can get the image to scale as I want by simply removing the `width="748"` from the `caption` tag, but the image caption disappears.

What is the proper way of having both the image and the caption scale to the same relative size on every device?

Comment: Usually wordpress does this by himselfs.. not sure how to do this manually, but you can upload post with image, print it on the screen and view page source to understand whats going on there

Comment: From block or classic editor? I can't use block editor for compatibility reasons.

Comment: classic editor https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/

Comment: I didn't get it, you want the image to shrink when the screen is small?